# How to get multiple values from a single <select> variable in HTML/PHP Codeigniter?

Tags: html, codeigniter

```
<select id="selectError" data-rel="chosen" name="emp_id" >
    <?php foreach ($all_data as $v) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $v->emp_name."x".$v->emp_id; ?>">
            <?= $v->emp_id; ?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

How do I send the two values which are separated by `x` in value to the database using Codeigniter?

Comment: what is "Codeignator" ??

Comment: do you mean the PHP framework Codeigniter? http://www.codeigniter.com/

Comment: ok, so after cleaning your code, I see that you are building your select dropdown dynamically. Your question is "how to send the selected value to your database", correct? if so? What have you tried so far? In traditional PHP how would you send that data to your DB?.  You need to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there's a lack of code from your controller, I am assuming you mean to pass the data to the left of the 'x' in the value to the database at the same time as the data to the right of the 'x', but as a separate piece of data, and also not including the 'x'.

in your controller, you can do

```
$data_parts = explode('x', $this->input->post('emp_id');
```

This will make `$data_parts` an array, and you can then use the information as `$data_parts[0]` and `$data_parts[1]` to pass to the database.

This will only work if the first and last parts of data don't contain an x.  I would strongly urge you to reconsider what you're trying to do with regards to the splitting of 'x', even if it means adding another column to your database which would be the value of the two items, plus the x.  You could then index that and then use the single value to pass through to search.

If you're looking to insert the two values alongside each other, you should consider splitting them into two different fields.